# ID Column Not Found in Spring Boot H2

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I asked similar question before but there's still not an answer.
Here is my code and log.

```
package com.yunus.ccApp.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "URUNLER")
public class UrunEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "URUN_ID")
    private int urunId;

    @Column(name = "DOGUM_AGIRLIGI")
    private Double dogumAgirligi;

    @Column(name = "DOGUM_SEKLI")
    private String dogumSekli;

    @Column(name = "DOGUM_TARIHI")
    private String dogumTarihi;

    @Column(name = "HAYVAN_ADI")
    private String hayvanAdi;

    @Column(name = "HAYVAN_ANNE_ADI")
    private String hayvanAnneAdi;

    @Column(name = "HAYVAN_CINSIYET")
    private String hayvanCinsiyet;

    @Column(name = "HAYVAN_IRKI")
    private String hayvanIrki;

    @Column(name = "HAYVAN_KUPE_NO")
    private int hayvanKupeNo;

    @Column(name = "HAYVAN_RESMI")
    private String hayvanResmi;

    @Column(name = "SUT_MIKTARI")
    private Double sutMiktari;

    @Column(name = "SUT_TARIHI")
    private String sutTarihi;

    @Column(name = "TOHUMA_HAZIR")
    private Boolean tohumaHazir;

    @Column(name = "URUN_TUTAR")
    private Double urunTutar;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Integer userId;


   
   //getter and setters
```

And here is my error code. I researched so much but I can't find anything. They say its about the key sensitivity but i don't think so. Because I try everything.

When I try to send a get post, i get this error everytime, in every query. Please help me.

```
SQL Error: 42122, SQLState: 42S22
```

2021-01-15 19:21:12.124 ERROR 13516 --- [nio-6161-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column "URUN_ID" not found [42122-200]
2021-01-15 19:21:12.145 ERROR 13516 --- [nio-6161-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/invoiceControl] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM URUNLER]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "URUN_ID" not found [42122-200]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]

Comment: Are you sure that the table is created with proper columns? Either via `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property or database migration tool like flyway. Can you enable H2 console and double check that the table is setup correctly?

Comment: How can I insert this inside of a yml file ?

Comment: you would add `spring.h2.console.enabled=true` (just in the yaml format with indents, since SO doesn't allow to use new line in comments). More info in the [baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database)

Comment: I already had this in my yml file sir.